# Delete Dynamic Element created

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a "delete" function or a - function if you will that deletes the dynamic element that I've created. As such the snippet I have creates a new dynamic element however I don't have a working subtraction method for deleting the last element creates. For example if someone hit the + button too many times, they would be able to hit the - button in order to delete the last element. In this case the last element would be the "wrapper".

Thanks, any help appreciated.

```js
  var template;
  var a = 1;
  window.onload = function() {
   template = document.querySelector("#wrapper").innerHTML;
   document.querySelector("#more_fields").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // tell the browser to not send the form
    document.getElementById('wrapper').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template); // add next segment
    document.querySelector("#wrapper > label:last-of-type").innerHTML = "Segment " + (++a) + ":"; //Updates Segment #
   });
  }

            function deleteMe(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var btn = document.getElementById("#wrapper");
   btn.onclick = function() {
    this.remove();
   };
  }
```

```html
   <div id="room_fileds">
    <div class="content" id="wrapper">
     <label name="seg[]" style="margin:0 0 10px 60px;display: inline;">Segment: 1</label>
     <div class="form-group" style="display: inline;">
      <label name=seg-in[] style="margin:0 0 10px 20px;display: inline;">IN :</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="seg-in" placeholder="HH:MM:SS:FF (DF)" type="text" style="Width:15%;display: inline;">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group" style="display: inline;">
      <label name=seg-out[] style="margin:0 0 10px 20px;display: inline;">OUT :</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="seg-out" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS:FF (DF)" style="Width:15%;display: inline;">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group" style="display: inline;">
      <label name=seg-dur[] style="margin:0 0 10px 20px;display: inline;">Duration:</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="seg-dur" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS:FF (DF)" style="Width:15%;display: inline;">
     </div>
     <br><br>
    </div>

   </div>
   <div style="text-align:right;">
    <div style="display:inline;text-align: right;">
     <button onclick="deleteMe();" style="height: 25px;width:13px;" id="less_fields">-</button>
    </div>
    <div style="display:inline;text-align: right;">
     <button id="more_fields">+</button>
    </div>
   </div>
   <br><br>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Comment: please update your snippet to include the `change()` method so that you have a [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Caught it just before you did, refresh your page =), thanks though

Comment: I'd suggest you put a wrapper around your segments of labels and identify them in some way (usually with a class) and then delete them. Separating them by `<br><br>` just makes it harder to determine what's grouped with what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're currently adding new segments as adjacent elements to the first, with no way of differentiating them via class nor id.

I'd first recommend modifying your code so that you wrap the segments elements in another div and give it the class `.segment`.  That way you can use the `document. querySelector` to target the last-of-type of class `.segment`.

```
var btn = document.querySelector("#wrapper > div.segment:last-of-type");
```

Check out this snippet:

```js
var template;
var a = 1;

window.onload = function() {
  template = document.querySelector("#wrapper").innerHTML;
  document.querySelector("#more_fields").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // tell the browser to not send the form
    document.getElementById('wrapper').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', template);
// add next segment
var numOfSegments = document.querySelectorAll("div.segment").length;
    document.querySelector("div.segment:last-of-type > label").innerHTML = "Segment " + (numOfSegments) + ":"; //Updates Segment #
       });
      }

                function deleteMe() {
       var btn = document.querySelector("#wrapper > div.segment:last-of-type");
       btn.remove();
      }
```

```html
      

       <div id="room_fileds">
  <div class="content" id="wrapper">
      <div class="segment">
        <label name="seg[]" style="margin:0 0 10px 60px;display: inline;">Segment: 1</label>
     <div class="form-group" style="display: inline;">
       <label name=seg-in[] style="margin:0 0 10px 20px;display: inline;">IN :</label>
       <input class="form-control" id="seg-in" placeholder="HH:MM:SS:FF (DF)" type="text" style="Width:15%;display: inline;">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group" style="display: inline;">
       <label name=seg-out[] style="margin:0 0 10px 20px;display: inline;">OUT :</label>
       <input class="form-control" id="seg-out" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS:FF (DF)" style="Width:15%;display: inline;">
     </div>

     <div class="form-group" style="display: inline;">
       <label name=seg-dur[] style="margin:0 0 10px 20px;display: inline;">Duration:</label>
       <input class="form-control" id="seg-dur" type="text" placeholder="HH:MM:SS:FF (DF)" style="Width:15%;display: inline;">
     </div>
      </div>
   </div>

 </div>
 <div style="text-align:right;">
   <div style="display:inline;text-align: right;">
   <button onclick="deleteMe();" style="height: 25px;width:13px;" id="less_fields">-</button>
 </div>
 <div style="display:inline;text-align: right;">
   <button id="more_fields">+</button>
   </div>
 </div>
 <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks for the input worked pretty well, only 1 issue, It would seem when I use the subtract button it resets my forum as if it were submitting

Comment: Ah, lol, probably because I removed commented out the preventDefault :).

Comment: haha yeah I added that in, But i get a rather odd error, bit hard to explain. But If i add a dynamic element all is well. If i try to subtract an element when a required field is not filled out the element will subtract and the form will display a "required field must be filled out" etc. When I subtract with all the required fields filled out the form submits. I've changed the deleteMe() method as such:   function deleteMe() {
   var btn = document.querySelector("#wrapper > div.segment:last-of-type");
   btn.remove();
   e.preventDefault();}